# Scale images in ng FlexLayout

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I'm having trouble understanding `@angular/flex-layout`. I've read numerous posts, blogs, and examples but can't get it to work, as I want it to.

I want to have one large `mat-card`, filling the complete width of the screen.
Inside this card I want some text and to the right of the text an image.

Below this full-width card I want 6 smaller cards. On a large screen 3 columns, a smaller screen 2 columns and the smallest screen 1 column.

Here's my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6iqcgo

With this demo I have several issues:

1. The image in the full-width card is not scaled proportionally. This distorts the image a lot on different screen sizes. How to fix this?
2. The 3 columns with the smaller cards are not evenly spaced. The 3rd card should go a bit more to the right. The second row, however, is good. How to fix this?
3. The first small card has less text and is less high. But I would like to have all card have the same height and preferably the `mat-card-actions` at the bottom. How to do this?
4. The top of the cards of the second row overlap the bottom of the cards of the first row. How to fix this?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I would suggest putting the img in a div that has `fxFlex` on it:

   ```
   <div fxFlex="0 0 50%">
     <img mat-card-image src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/79/3b/ca/793bca86db40af44ad03534f6927626b.jpg" alt="Free image">
   </div>
   ```
2. Remove the `fxLayoutGap="32px"` from the containing div.
3. They all appear the same height to me. For the actions to be at the bottom of the card you should be able to use `mat-card-footer` to attach to the bottom of the card.
4. You can set a `margin-top` or `margin-bottom` on the `mat-card` to add a gap when it wraps.

Comment: Thanks Mitch, I've made the changes you suggested and made a few more and now it is working as expected. Except for my #3 question. The first small card is less high. But I can live with it for now. I've updated https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6iqcgo. I'll accept your answer.